# The onReceive() of Broadcast receiver gets called for all the proximity alerts. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-geofence

I am an android newbie, learning android and i was developing a simple Geofencing application.
Everything works fine when i insert a single GeoFence. But when i use more than 2 Geofences, the onReceive of all the fences are fired and the notification of all the Geofences are created on top on one another. I tried searching the web, and did not come up with any solution. Can anybody help me with what i am doing wrong?
and thanks a lot. :)

Here is the code for the Service class i have written:

```
package com.example.multigeofence;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class GeoFenceService extends Service {

    LocationManager lm;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    BufferedReader bur;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
                new MyLocationListener());


        addProximityAlert(12.955299,77.679977,"Tata Elxsi",50);
        addProximityAlert(12.187497,76.852970,"Mall",50);
        addProximityAlert(12.552929,77.079977,"Dummy place",50);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude,
            String name, int rad) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("idontknowyvusethis");
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, 0);

        lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, rad, -1, proximityIntent);
        // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from
        // the alert region is detected

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("idontknowyvusethis");
        registerReceiver(new proximityIntentReceiver(name, rad), filter);

    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for Receiver class:

```
package com.example.multigeofence;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class proximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    private String name;
    private int rad;

    public proximityIntentReceiver(String name, int rad) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rad = rad;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
            String abc = "";

            Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

            if (entering) {
                abc = "You are entering " + name + "! Beware!";
                Toast.makeText(context, "inside if : " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("GeoGeo", "inside if : " + name);
            } else
                abc = "You are exiting " + name + "! Plz com bak :(";

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent i = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    i, 0);

            Notification notification = createNotification();
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, abc, "The radius is: "
                    + rad, pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }


    private Notification createNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification();

        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

        return notification;
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multigeofence"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".GeoFenceService"
            android:enabled="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: can u post manifest?

Comment: @DIVA Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question with the manifest. :)

Comment: you are getting call onReceive multiple times right?

Comment: Yes, onReceive of all the 3 locations are getting called when i enter or leave any 1 fence.

Comment: ok only idea i can provide you is [try this]: 1. i can see that u hv registered the receiver dynamically..change it to static i mean declare it in manifest and use it..2. Resaon for the same : some of the broadcast seems to be sticky in android hence onReceive is called mutiple times ..3. After my reserach i basically found that static call of broadcast solve this issue..and the thing is whenever u register that time only it will fire onReceive...thats stick behaviour...let me know if any issues

Comment: @DIVA am really sorry for this dumbness. But if i statically register the receiver, how can i send the parameters to the receiver class? i am sending the parameters in this line - registerReceiver(new proximityIntentReceiver(name, rad), filter); But its not possible to send the parameters if i register it statically. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You should register only one receiver instead of three. To find out which location triggered notification you should add some data to your intent passed to getBroadcast, something like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("idontknowyvusethis");
intent.putExtra( "fenceName", name );
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

This intent will returned to you in onReceive:

```
String locationName = intent.getStringExtra( "fenceName" );
```